# How do I stretch a div to be the height of the document body, not the viewport? (included code)

Tags: html, css

All the examples I've seen say to do the below code, but this does **not** work (see jsfiddle below).

```
html { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
.stretchable { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
```

Showing it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/yVDXQ/481/

How do I use CSS only to force a div to be the height of the document body, not the window?

Comment: it's not clear what are you trying to accomplish. You want to have that grey box to be the height of those a's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closer... your body element is not the full height of the content. Remove the *height: 100%* and instead add *position: relative* to the body element. Here is a fork of the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7j8vrnr8/

Remember that absolute positioned elements have their height/width based on the first relative positioned element as you move up the hierarchy.

```
position: relative
```

Comment: This fixed it. Why does a height of 100% on the body cause the problem?

Comment: This goes back to the positioning rules. By setting height: 100% on html, you are setting it to 100% height of the viewport. Then setting 100% of body of course inherits that. For learning purposes try going back to height: 100% on the body and removing height: 100% on html, and it should work correctly as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to remove `height:100%` for `body` – otherwise the body will only be as high as the viewport (with the rest of the content overflowing it).

And then, since your `.stretchable` element is positioned absolutely, you simply remove any height and min-height from that completely (so that effectively `height:auto` is in place) – and position it from the `top` *and* `bottom`, so that those two values determine its height. (`position:relative` added for `body`, so that this element gets taken as point of reference for the absolute positioning).

http://jsfiddle.net/yVDXQ/484/

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about top/bottom/left/right. Just keep the min-height in place on the inner (.container) element.